# Constructors taking references in C++

Tags: c++, reference, constructor

I'm trying to create constructor taking reference to an object. After creating object using reference I need to prints field values of both objects. Then I must delete first object, and once again show values of fields of both objects. My class Person looks like this :

```
class Person {   
    char* name;
    int age;
public:

    Person(){
        int size=0;
        cout << "Give length of char*" << endl;
        cin >> size;
        name = new char[size];      
        age = 0;
    }

    ~Person(){
        cout << "Destroying resources" << endl;
        delete[] name;
        delete age;
    }  

void init(char* n, int a) {
    name = n;
    age = a;
} 
};
```

Here's my implementation (with the use of function show() ). My professor said that if this task is written correctly it will return an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {   
    char* name;
    int age;
public:

    Person(){
        int size=0;
        cout << "Give length of char*" << endl;
        cin >> size;
        name = new char[size];      
        age = 0;
    }

    Person(const Person& p){
        name = p.name;
        age = p.age;
    }

    ~Person(){
        cout << "Destroying resources" << endl;
        delete[] name;
        delete age;
    }  

void init(char* n, int a) {
    name = n;
    age = a;
}


void show(char* n, int a){
    cout << "Name: " << name << "," << "age: " << age << "," << endl; 
}

}; 


int main(void) {
    Person *p = new Person;  
    p->init("Mary", 25);

    p->show();

    Person &p = pRef;
    pRef->name = "Tom";
    pRef->age = 18;

    Person *p2 = new Person(pRef);

    p->show();
    p2->show();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Constructors for C++ objects][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856156/constructors-for-c-objects

Comment: First priority: remove the `init` function and write an appropriate constructor instead. This is bad C++, don’t go down that road.

Comment: @Konrad: I'm not entirely sure I agree with you there.  There is a good argument for doing as little as possible in the constructor and doing more work in an Init function.  Amongst other things it allows you to return errors without resorting to exception handling.  That said he's allocating in the constructor so that would blow my point out of the water, hence saying i don't *entirely* agree ;)

Comment: @Goz: I think this kind of pattern is a mistake. It looks like `C` where it could  (*should*) be `C++`. Doing so can lead to have uninitialized instances (aka. "invalid objects") and is counter-intuitive. Using an exception to abort a constructor is clean: if the initialization went wrong, then object is properly destroyed **and** you have all the information you need in the caught exception. On the other hand, you have the guaranty that any instance of `Person` is correctly built.

Comment: Remove `delete age;` from the destructor: `age` has not been allocated dynamically so you must not delete it.

Comment: @ereOn:  I totally see where you are coming from but I'd argue that this can make for a problem when someone else is dealing with your code.  Its not always obvious that something throws.  If your code then throws when someone isn't expecting it too it can give you a few problems.  A return value is a very explicit way of saying its failed.  You can see instantly that the function returns something and it can't do something you aren't expecting it too.  To add to that I, personally, find C++ exception handling to be quite the ugliest thing I've ever come across.  Error codes FTW!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your copy constructor is that it merely assigns p.name:

```
name = p.name // Now this and p hold a pointer to the same memory
```

Since both `this` and `p` now hold a pointer to the same memory location, whichever one destructs first will free the memory while the second one will be holding a pointer to a non-existent object. Subsequently using that pointer or deleting it will result in undefined behavior. The solution is to allocate a new array for name and copy the contents of p.name into that array, so that the memory isn't shared.

Likewise, your init function overwrites name, ignoring the fact that memory has been allocating (it is a memory leak) and also ignoring the fact that the string will later be destructed (even though the caller probably expects to own and free that string, itself).  Also, I should point out that your show function takes a parameter "n", but uses "name", instead. Your show function probably shouldn't take any parameters (indeed, the way you call it implies that it doesn't), given that all the needed fields are already present in your class (or maybe you intended for that to be a freestanding function that takes the fields of the class?). You should take another look at your code for additional errors.

Comment: It's worse than that. When the second object destructs it will delete a pointer that was already deleted. If you're lucky the OS will spot that and kill the process for freeing an address it doesn't own; if you're less lucky all hell will break loose, silently. Also, there's no assignment operator (or, rather, there's the unsuitable default assignment operator).

Comment: @Wilhelm, it doesn't get worse than undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior, it can blow up, either way. That said, you are right, there are other errors. I simply looked at the copy constructor, since that was the only thing mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to compile your code (it is usually a good idea to compile code before posting it on SO.) It contains several errors and compiler will show them. Second part will be to change the following:

```
p->init("Mary", 25);
```

to

```
{
  std::string mary("Mary");
  p->init(mary.c_str(), 25);
}
```

It should give you an error at runtime and it will give you a chance to find a problem in your implementation.

Comment: If I was the prof and I was trying to teach them something about char* strings, about pointers, and about memory leaks, and somebody flipped to using std::string when I hadn't taught it yet, I would not be happy. While STL solves many problems in real life, arbitrarily using it in an assignment about pointers, because pointers are hard, is not a good strategy in a course.

Comment: `std::string` here only to show that pointer to `char*` may become invalid. Note that I used curly brackets to limit the scope of variable `mary`. Before that OP used pointer to the string literal which is valid all the time while program running.

Comment: I've tried to add tips in my answer so OP could find all error by itself.